# Redis Connection - Multiplex it or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

In terms of performance, is it better to multiplex 1 connection object across multiple requests or to give each request it's own connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what redis client are you using? StackExchange.Redis is **explicitly designed** to be multiplexed and shared between multiple requests (or any other parallel load); other clients may not be, and may require you to *lease from a pool* per request (or for some portion of a request). There is quite a lot of overhead involved in establishing a connection with redis (optionally DNS, sockets, optionally TLS, and a bit of chit-chat backwards and forwards to determine the redis server configuration), so you don't want to completely establish a new *underlying* connection per request (even if it is fast).

Comment: i'm handling about 20 requests/sec per vm (usually 2-3 vm)... any suggestions on how many connections should i keep up?

Comment: @Leonardo I know absolutely nothing about your workload or the redis operations you are trying to perform; doing lots of "get"/"set" is very different to running "sinterstore" of 17 sets, for example, or running "keys"; or complex Lua, or multi/exec, etc. And you still haven't told me what redis library you are using, **which matters**. But: stackoverflow.com using StackExchange.Redis runs at a *much* higher request rate per node, and uses a single redis connection per app-domain (per target redis etc) for all concurrent requests. But we design for performance very much a non-negotiable factor

Comment: @Leonardo additional thought: even with just "get"/"set" - there's a huge difference between values of 200 bytes vs values of 20MB

Comment: thank you for your input Marc, today i'm using StackExchange.Redis and i only do Get/Set and try to keep the keys to a size under 60kb (i read it somewhere that i should try to keep the key sizes as small as possible)... my redis is reporting a traffic of around 4 mb/s and peaking 8mb/s and my regular number of operations is 150k per minute